# How to generalize repetitive parsing with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am learning to use Parsec by parsing lines in a text file. What I have is the following:

```
import Text.Parsec (ParseError, parse)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import Text.Parsec.Char (anyChar, digit, char, oneOf)
import Control.Monad (void)
import qualified Text.Parsec.Combinator as C

data Action =
  ActionA Int Int
  | ActionB Int Int Int Int Int
  | ActionC Int Int Int
  deriving (Show)

parseWithEof :: Parser a -> String -> Either ParseError a
parseWithEof p = parse (p <* C.eof) ""

parseActionA :: Parser Action
parseActionA = do
  char 'A'
  void $ oneOf " "
  a <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  b <- C.many1 digit
  return $ ActionA (read a) (read b)

parseActionB :: Parser Action
parseActionB = do
  char 'B'
  void $ oneOf " "
  a <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  b <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  c <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  d <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  e <- C.many1 digit
  return $ ActionB (read a) (read b) (read c) (read d) (read e)

parseActionC :: Parser Action
parseActionC = do
  char 'C'
  void $ oneOf " "
  a <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  b <- C.many1 digit
  void $ oneOf " "
  c <- C.many1 digit
  return $ ActionC (read a) (read b) (read c)
```

I would like to be able to generalize these parsing functions since I feel that they are repetitive. I don't know if that is possible, or how it is possible.

I would also like to know if it is possible to have a function like this:

```
parseAction :: String -> Either ParseError Action
parseAction input = 
    parseWithEof parseActionA input
    <some operator|combinator> parseWithEof parseActionB input
    <some operator|combinator> parseWithEof parseActionC input
```

So when `parseAction` receives a string as parameter it will try to parse it with the different parsers. I expect it to return (Left ParseError) if no parser could parse the input and (Right Action) if a parser succeeded in parsing the input.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Applicative combinators you can write:

```
num = do oneOf " "; fmap read (C.many1 digit)

parseActionA = ActionA <$> (char 'A' >> num) <*> num

parseActionB = ActionB <$> (char 'B' >> num) <*> num <*> num <*> num <*> num
```

For your second question, just use `<|>` with `try`

```
parseAction = try parseActionA <|> try parseActionB <|> try parseActionC
```

Note - `try` shouldn't be needed on the last parser, but it doesn't hurt to have it. Also, if you know enough about how your parsers work you may be able to do away with some of the `try`s.

Comment: That simplifies it somewhat but I still have to write n times the `<*> num` part. Is there a way to automatically repeat that?

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion See if you can use `replicateM`.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid How would you use `replicateM` since it returns a list? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @ErikR You are using `try parseActionA <|> try parseActionB`, but according to this article (http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/05/parsec-try-a-or-b-considered-harmful/) we should try to reduce the scope of `try`. Is this the same case or is it different?

Comment: `count :: Stream s m t => Int -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m [a]`

Essentially you can end up with something to the effect of
`parseActionB = do char 'B'; ([a,b,c,d,e]) <- count 5 num; return $ ActionB a b c d e`

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion putting `try` before every parser is safe. When you know more about how Parsec works you can remove the ones you don't need for better efficiency.